# Пишу код,и invalid syntax!В чём ошибка?

Tags: python

```
while True:
    a=['s','h','p']
    print(a)
    if q==1:
        a.pop()
    else q==2:
        a.clear()
```

Итог:invalid syntax

Comment: Наверное, вы имели ввиду `elif q==2:`

Answer (score 2):

Все просто, в `python` после `else` нельзя писать каких либо условий. Если вам нужно условие в том же `if`-е, тогда вам надо написать `elif q == 2:`